# How to set jvm heap size in shell script

Tags: java, shell, jvm

In  korn shell script I have this.

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /xxxxxx/Classpath.sh
export JAVAHOME=/usr/java5
export PATH=$JAVAHOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
export CLASSPATH
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
java .......
```

Getting the below error. Tried the java options as above. But, still getting the same error?? Please need help with this. Thanks.

```
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '......trc' in response to an event
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable for `JVM_ARGS` and `PROG_ARGS`, place `VM_ARGS` and `PROG_ARGS` at appropriate positions like below

`java <JVM_ARGS> com.test.Main <PROG_ARGS>`

Example:-

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${CONFIG_DIR};

JVM_ARGS="-Dprocess.name=MainProcess -Xmx1024M -Xms256M "

PROG_ARGS="/home/saravana/files"

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JVM_ARGS com.test.Main $PROG_ARGS
```

add all your dependent lib in classpath variable,
add your JVM_ARGS like starting & max heap, process name,
add your program args in PROG_ARGS

JVM_ARGS, PROG_ARGS are just variable names you can keep any names

Comment: #!/bin/ksh 
. /xxxxxx/Classpath.sh 
export JAVAHOME=/usr/java5 
export PATH=$JAVAHOME/bin:$PATH 
export PATH export CLASSPATH
JVMARGS=-Xmx1024m 
java $JVMARGS com.......